# Meaning of infrastructure & application code in domain-driven design

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

On the Domain-Driven Design [website](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/118) I see:

> Concentrate all the code related to
>   the domain model in one layer and
>   isolate it from the user interface,
>   application, and infrastructure code.
>   The domain objects, free of the
>   responsibility of displaying
>   themselves, storing themselves,
>   managing application tasks, and so
>   forth, can be focused on expressing
>   the domain model. This allows a model
>   to evolve to be rich enough and clear
>   enough to capture essential business
>   knowledge and put it to work.

What "goes in" the *infrastructure code*? Does this mean supporting frameworks (for logging, for example)?

I presume "application code" means the domain objects (i.e. the domain model)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Infrastructure** code would be implementations of repositories for instance. You might have in-memory or Hibernate repositories that live in the infrastructure layer, while their interfaces live in the domain layer.

**Application** code controls the domain objects. It defines services that take user commands and invoke business logic on domain objects, but no business logic lives in that layer.

Comment: So do repositories (in the design pattern sense, not, as I understand it, in the sense of repositories in your answer) typically live in the domain model, or in a separate data access component?

Comment: ...and would things like IOC containers, logging and metrics collection subsystems typically be described as residing in the infrastructure code "layer"?